# What species is Matron Corfelia?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who, the adipose raised on earth are cared for by their 'wet nurse', Matron Corfelia, in *Partners in Crime*.

Functionally, Corfelia appears human, but I don't know for certain. She isn't an adult Adipose, as they appear in a later episode:
[image: Adult adipose in a bar]

Could she be disguised as human? Or belong to a near human species?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing an adult adipose, but I'm pretty sure your image doesn't depict one either: The little thing on the bar is a "baby" adipose and the creature in the back left of the image Slitheen (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitheen)

Comment: I took the picture from a mention on the whovian wiki. Anyway, what would a baby be doing at a bar?

Comment: @onewho http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Adipose#Technology

Comment: The only image of an adult adipose in that article is the comic one. And if you take into comparison the size of the microphone then that adipose would be about human sized.

Comment: @Pureferret - I'm pretty sure that's not an adult; that scene demonstrates it being comically childish in behavior (a pratfall occurs seconds after that image) and speaking in the baby talk we heard in the initial episode, compared to the comic that shows it as clearly coherent reported.  Dunno why there's a baby in a bar, but, then, bars aren't taboo to children everywhere, nor were they historically... so for an alien culture, I see no real issue.

Comment: @onewho - You might find this interesting; [Concept art of an adult Adipose](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144868/20774)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Her species is as yet unidentified.** She was considered in disguise, though by what means was never revealed. Whatever her species, it appeared to have all of the frailties of humanity as she fell to her death. She was released from a tractor beam and murdered by the Adult Adipose who were removing witnesses to their breaking of the Shadow Proclamation.

Comment: Would her possessing sonic tech narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: Not really. While there may not be many races that can create one, it shouldn't be that hard for races whose technology is past a certain point. The future that Jack Harkness came from had similar sonic weaponry, and there are a few other examples of such technology available. There were a number of races whose technology was comparable with the Gallifreyans at some levels. I suspect such a useful tool would have plenty of people trying to copy, replicate, or create knock-offs.